# How to write a JQL to retrieve the summation of a numeric field in the Jira for an issue list?

Tags: report, jira-plugin, jql, jira-agile

In my Jira project, I have two numeric fields ‘Design Effort (hrs)’ and ‘Execution Effort (hrs)’. I need to write a JQL query to get the summation of these two fields for an issue list.

For example, If I write a JQL as below (Refer the screenshot) to get the summation of the ‘Design Effort (hrs)’ for two issues, I will get the below error.

[image: JQL Error]

How can I modify the query to get what I needed?